# How to add video as third-party tool in Cloudflare Zaraz?

Tags: cookies, cloudflare, zaraz

I have a vimeo video on my Next.js site:

```
<iframe
    height="350"
    className="embed-responsive-item"
    title="video"
    src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234"
    frameBorder="0"
    allowFullScreen
></iframe>
```

This sends user data to Vimeo and sets a cookie. Therefore, I would like to add this as a third-party service to Cloudflare Zaraz. But I don't understand the logic of how to do this...

I suppose I could remove the above code block from my application and instead add the code block as Custom HTML as a tool in Cloudflare Zaraz. But that would of course not work as the application then still has no idea where to display that piece of code after the user has given consent.

How to do this?